# Printing previous answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a game where the user has to try and guess the combination of a code.  I want the user to be able to see his previous attempts that he has had.  However at the moment I can only get the div box's that they are in to display their most recent code.

Here is my code where the function is.

```
Game.countAnimals = function(playerGo){

        var count = {bulls:0, cows:0};
        Game.counter = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < playerGo.length; i++) {
            var digPresent = playerGo.indexOf(Game.score[i]);
            if (playerGo[i] == Game.score[i]) {count.bulls++;}
            else if (digPresent>=0) {count.cows++;}
            Game.counter++
            if (count.bulls == playerGo.length && Game.counter < 7){
                console.log("you have won")}
                else if (count.bulls !== playerGo.length && Game.counter < 7) {
                    console.log("Sorry Homes")}
                    else if (count.bulls !== playerGo.length && Game.counter > 7 ){console.log ("you lose");}




                }
                $(".scoreboard1").html(count.cows);
                $(".scoreboard2").html(count.bulls);
```

Comment: try changing `$(".scoreboard1").html(count.cows);` to `$(".scoreboard1").html($(".scoreboard1").html()+count.cows);`

Comment: @depperm No. `$(".scoreboard1").append('<br/>'+count.cows);`